# SQL Server 2012: quickly INSERT millions of rows from SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Apologies if I am enraging the forum with repetitive question. Couldn't find the right solution in the forum, hence posting it.

I need to fetch 129991763 rows into a cursor or temp table or a staging table quickly and process them into another table. And this destination table is also huge table.

Currently I am using `INSERT` using `SELECT` statement (the `SELECT` is nested 4 levels) used hints like Option (FAST 1000), MAXDOP 1, RECOMPILE ...etc...

The procedure is consuming lot of time and showing no results or not getting completed at all.

Previously I used a cursor with the same hints; but as it was also running more than 22 hours; I switched to `INSERT` using `SELECT`.

Literally, I need to stop the execution for above both methods.

And to be honest, I am beginner in SQL Server database.

Even if specifically filter out the records in `SELECT` based on criteria; still the process needs to broken 4 or 5 chunks and these chunks are also taking more than 4 - 5 hours to complete.

Please help.

Thanks
Pradyumna

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Try to create approx 1300 batches of around 100,000 rows each from 129,991,763 records. Don't use cursor. You also need to validate if your query is not being blocked by other processes. If your destination table has index, you may consider dropping it depending upon ratio of rows already exists to rows to be inserted.

Comment: Try to disable or drop all indexes and foreign key constraints on your target table; make sure the **database file** is large enough to hold all the data, so that it doesn't have to constantly extend in size. But inserting **millions of rows** will never be lightning fast - it will **take its time** - you cannot "optimize" that away - period.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta: Sorry to enrage you. One more small help. Agreed I am asking you a basic question. Could you please guide me on how to divided SELECT statement into batches. I will definitely use it. It would even be used to print to console whether any record is Inserted or not. Yes, we are dropping the indexes on destination table.

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, we've already include the command to Disable the indexes on Destination table. The database has sufficient size for operation. Actually my efforts are not even showing at least a single record is Inserted or not. The procedure is running for 20 hours and there is no message printed to say a record is INSERTED. I have to stop the code abruptly. Hence seeking for expert's help.

Comment: @JamesZ: I am looking for a possible solution to load the huge massive data volumes quickly. My efforts are in wrong direction and not at all resulting in normal.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86517/breaking-a-big-insert-query-into-smaller-ones

Comment: I'm afraid we don't really have enough information to help you; you'll need to do more investigation locally to figure out what the bottleneck is, as there are too many factors we can't guess. The problem might be that your data is running over a slow network link, or that your query code is badly-written, or that the FAST 1000 hint is slowing things down, or relate to your clustering key, or be any one of literally hundreds of other reasons. Without knowing your query, your data, your infrastructure, your query plans, your I/O statistics, we'll simply be guessing.

Comment: Please update the question with a few more details such as your source and destination tables structure (column names, data types, indexes if any). Also, please add the query you were using. Have you checked the execution plan, IO statistics etc?

Comment: Experts, first of all apologies for being late in updating the status and responding to comments. I did the the following to encounter the challenge: divided the INSERT operation into 4 chunks.

Comment: SELECT the required data on 4 different requirements. For 2 chunks it is straight forward direct INSERT INTO using SELECT; but for 2 chunks I would have to DECLARE a CURSOR or use Temporary Tables. Currently testing is in progress. So far the 2 chunks having direct INSERT are responding normal. Further data verification and validation will be done and I would need to review the results of CURSOR and TempTable process repeatedly for better results.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used BULK INSERT with reasonable success, but I suspect the suggestion of breaking it into chunks and dropping indexes would still be wise.  You can find some details on it here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188365.aspx

Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help; wanted to load the data from multiple tables using SELECT. I am sorry, I would be wrong here. BULK INSERT in SQL Server2012 will be working for flat files. I am looking for INSERT using SELECT. Yes, Indexes are dropped. As you suggested to dividing the  process into batches/chunks. I am asking for extended help on dividing it into batches.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, you will probably be best using an SSIS package to pull it across. With this you can also transform the data if needed. I would still recommend keeping indexes off the table you are inserting the data into where possible. You'll need to have a bit of a read but hard to explain on here due to the use of the GUI.

Good luck